# Is there a word to describe a company who keep their clients for life?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

To cut a long story short, I'm in the process of setting up a marketing agency and am trying to come up with a concise way of summing up my target market. Essentially I am targeting companies whose services would normally be considered 'expensive' but whose clients often last a lifetime. Examples of companies that would match this criteria would be lawyers, financial advisors, dentists, plastic surgeons, high-end hair salons, bespoke clothing designers etc. -

I was initially considering the term 'professional services firms' but felt that this was too closely tied to the corporate members of the above list.

Any suggestions very much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but such markets typically have high https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switching_barriers. Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in.

Comment: Maybe, to put it in a more positive light, you could call them _trusted_ vendors/firms/providers/professionals/companies. Or _reputable_ also is used quite a bit.

Comment: That's given me another slant to possibly go at this from so thanks for that!

Comment: @Keepthesemind perhaps 'prestigious/well-respected service providers'

Comment: I suggest the key word here should be _trust_. This is (mostly, but not completely) why people don't switch too often between the types of businesses mentioned by you. Although words like _loyalty_ and _retention_ may also be appropriate. So, maybe 'high-trust businesses' or 'high-loyalty businesses' or 'high-retention businesses' (but the last one sounds odd, although it would literally describe your market).

Comment: Sometimes referred to as *client partnering*.